# Windows stuck at windows startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-restore

I just made a restore point with my Windows 7, the restore point date was yesterday. After getting that and shutting down and doing the restore point stuff, my computer restarts. But it gets stuck at Windows startup.

I shut my PC down and tried again but it's still stuck. I tried booting in safe mode but it gets stuck at 'CLASSPNP.SYS'. I tried those other safe modes, like with networking, etc. It still gets stuck. I tried using Last Good Known Configuration, it still gets stuck in "starting windows".

I tried startup repair but I only get that blue Windows screen, just that blue background with the white designs without any texts. I tried all of that again and again and still no change. I tried starting windows normally, again it's still stuck. I don't have any Windows 7 installation disk I don't know what to do please help.

Comment: Stuck for how long? Let it sit at that screen for a few hours, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid activation key for windows (usually found on the computer itself) you can download the installation media from Microsoft : https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows7  -  If this does not work there are other legal ways to download the installation disk  -  I will post you links to them in the comments if this method does not work.

Once you have the installation media you can create an installation DVD/USB - you will need to use a friend's computer to download and create the installation media.

Next, boot your computer from the installation DVD/USB.  First try repairing your current installation using a system image.  Run a disk check as well by pressing `shift+F10` to open a command prompt after you reach the installation screen and then typing `chkdsk C: /r`.  If this does not solve your problem then go ahead and reinstall the OS.